# DLToolkit.Forms.FlowListView for Maui

Tags: c#, maui

I'm currently migrating a Xamarin.Forms app to .net Maui, the package DLToolkit.Forms has probably not been maintained since 2018 and I can't use it anymore. Does anyone know of a similar tool?

Comment: Why can't you use ListView or CollectionView here? Why do you need FlowListView exactly?

Comment: The application I'm working on is still completely new territory for me, I've only just started working with this app and haven't  the time to look at exactly what exactly this tool does differently, but I'll catch up on that. I wanted to ask in advance whether there is a similar tool.

Comment: The guy that made FlowListView is Daniel and I am pretty sure lately he's been busy, that's the same reason FFImageLoading hasn't been moved to Maui either.

Comment: @FreakyAli For showing multiple items on the UI I am using `DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView`. Normal listview has no such feature, I am also block with this same issue.

Comment: I am in the same boat with a Xamarin Forms update.